# Do sed and awk provide anything that I can't trivially do in a bash script with plain bash?

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk, sed

I learned bash before I learned sed and awk. Many things that I see people using sed, awk, and sometimes even grep for, I seem to just be able to use bash logic for. I'm wondering **what are some use-cases for sed and awk that would make them useful to learn as someone who is already a bash scripter?** This is surprisingly difficult to determine without already knowing sed and awk thoroughly.

Comment: Yes, speed. bash is notoriously slow. Particularly reading files. From a merely style point of view, bash often requires tons more syntax than something like awk. As you learn awk and sed, you'll get a feel for where they are particularly useful. It's a good thing to have many tools in your toolkit.

Comment: Related: [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716)

Comment: That's very much like asking "what are some use-cases for C and Java that would make them useful to learn as someone who is already an assembly code programmer?".

Answer (score 9):

This is sort of like asking if there's any point in learning how to drive a car if you already know how to crawl on your hands and knees. Yes, bash can be abused for some basic text manipulation or simple math, but it is the slowest tool there is for that, the syntax is complicated and it is very, very easy to get it wrong. In addition, shells, including bash, cannot do floating point arithmetic which greatly limits what you can achieve using nothing but the shell.

Any one of those reasons would be enough, but here's a very simple example. Take a file that is nothing more complicated than the numbers from 1 to 100,000 shuffled into a random order:

```
seq 100000 | shuf > file
```

Now, let's select all odd numbers. In bash, you could do something like this:

```
$ time while read num; do [[ $num =~ [24680]$ ]] || echo $num; done < file > newfile

real    0m3.481s
user    0m2.648s
sys     0m0.801s
```

That took around 3 seconds on my machine. What if we do the same thing, but with the numbers between 1 and 1,000,000?

```
seq 1000000 | shuf > file
```

And:

```
$ time while read num; do [[ $num =~ [24680]$ ]] || echo $num; done < file > newfile

real    0m32.483s
user    0m25.035s
sys     0m7.343s
```

That's already more than 30 seconds! Now, compare the same thing in `awk` that can do proper math:

```
$ time awk '$1 % 2 !=0' file > newfile 

real    0m0.344s
user    0m0.340s
sys     0m0.003s
```

Less than a second. And how about sed, using the same text-matching approach/

```
$ time sed -n '/[13579]$/p' file > newfile 

real    0m0.280s
user    0m0.273s
sys     0m0.007s
```

Less than a second, once more. So what if we go up to 10,000,000?

```
$ seq 1000000 | shuf > file
$ time awk '$1 % 2 !=0' file > newfile 

real    0m4.081s
user    0m3.896s
sys     0m0.090s

$ time sed -n '/[13579]$/p' file > newfile 

real    0m2.898s
user    0m2.683s
sys     0m0.111s

$ time while read num; do [[ $num =~ [24680]$ ]] || echo $num; done < file > newfile1

real    5m42.445s
user    4m25.687s
sys     1m15.241s
```

As you can see, the shell solution is orders of magnitude slower than the non-shell ones. And a file with 10 million lines is not a particularly rare thing. This is just a 76M text file.
Also, both non-shell solutions are much shorter (in terms of character length) and, once you know their syntax, much simpler.

So, this is a case of "when all you have is a hammer, everything looks like a nail". Yes, bash could do some of the things you can do with tools like `sed` or `awk` but it is much slower and not as good at the job.

Comment: good demonstration of the cases where `sed`, `awk`, etc are useful.. to make a complete answer, perhaps show some cases where `bash` features like parameter expansion is better to use than calling an external process? I know the question isn't about that, but showing this will prevent possible misuse of external programs for everything